# PyQt5 - Button clicked.connect() - No suggestions

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I create applications using **QtDesigner **by loading **.ui** files.

Everything works but why there are no suggestions when writing code for `clicked.connect(some_def)` e.g.:

I have python 3.11.3 and PyCharm IDE installed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drfQN.png)

code example:

`from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAbstractButton
import sys

class Ui(QMainWindow):
def **init**(self):
super(Ui, self).**init**()
uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)

```
    #self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Print", self)
    self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'printButton')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.printButtonPressed)
    self.show()

def printButtonPressed(self):
    print('printButtonPressed')
```

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()`

I tested on python 3.10.11 and python 3.8.10 but the suggestions still don't work.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that pycharm wouldn't be able to recognise objects defined in a ui file (which is xml) that is loaded as runtime. If you want auto-completion, you can use [pyuic](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5) to create static python modules instead.

Comment: Hi
So I have to convert ".ui" to ".py", load the MainWindow class and it should work.
I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it could be because of the flag on `def printButtonPressed(self):`
It could also be a problem with the text editor, you would have to look into it as I'm not experienced with editors outside of vscode.

Comment: you could try to repair or reinstall the editor, or just try a new one

Comment: It's just weird because `self.button.clicked.connect(self.printButtonPressed)` works but there is no suggestion by the IDE that I can use `clicked` and `connect`.

Comment: reinstall all when install python version

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I'm need to convert ".ui' to ".py" and load class Ui_MainWindow.

Example working code (suggestions worked fine).

`    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAbstractButton
import sys
from gui import Ui_MainWindow

class Ui(QMainWindow):
def **init**(self):
super(Ui, self).**init**()
# uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)

```
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printButtonPressed)

    self.show()

def printButtonPressed(self):
    print('printButtonPressed')
```

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()    `